# jqgrid load from database does not work filterToolbar

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm working with Asp.net MVC4, jqgrid 4.4.4  and jquery 1.9
The jqGrid is loaded from a query to the database, but I can not filter the fields, when I put a value doesn't search, it shows me the same values, but when I define in jqgrid the value loadonce: true only in the first search page, How I can resolve this problem? Where I should be modify the code?

This is my code, jqgrid:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#tbBuscaRec").jqGrid({  
            url: '@Url.Action("DatosBuscaPersona", "raTabPersonaReclamante")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',    
            postData: { Parametro: Param },
            colNames: ['Id', 'IdPer', 'Doc', 'CI/NIT', 'Nombres', 'Apellido Paterno', 'Apellido Materno', 'Apellido Esposo'],
            colModel:
            [
              { name: 'ip_idpersona', index: 'ip_idpersona', formatter: 'number', hidden: true },
              { name: 'ip_idpersonadoc', index: 'ip_idpersonadoc', formatter: 'text', hidden: true },
              { name: 'ip_partipodoc', index: 'ip_partipodoc', align: 'left', width: '4', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { readonly: true }, search: false },
              { name: 'ip_nrodoc', index: 'ip_nrodoc', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '8', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { readonly: true} },
              { name: 'ip_nombres', index: 'ip_nombres', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '15', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { readonly: true} },
              { name: 'ip_appaterno', index: 'ip_appaterno', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '15', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { readonly: true } },
              { name: 'ip_apmaterno', index: 'ip_apmaterno', sortable: true, align: 'left', width: '15', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { readonly: true} },
              { name: 'ip_apesposo', index: 'ip_apesposo', sortable: false, align: 'left', width: '15', editable: true, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { readonly: true} }
            ],
            pager: '#pg_tbBuscaRec',
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 200, 300],
            sortname: 'ip_nombres',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            rownumbers: true,
            multiselect: false,
            gridview: true,
            height: 180,
            width: 490,
            ignoreCase: true,
//            loadonce: true,
        });
    });
    jQuery("#tbBuscaRec").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pg_tbBuscaRec', { view: false, edit: false, add: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true, closeOnEscape: true });
    jQuery("#tbBuscaRec").jqGrid('filterToolbar');
    jQuery("#tbBuscaRec").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);
```

Comment: if you want use `loadonce: true` the controller action `@Url.Action("DatosBuscaPersona", "raTabPersonaReclamante")` have to return **all data** (instead of one page of data) just sorted corresponding to `sidx` and `sord`. Alternatively you have to implement **server side filtering** (see the answer of Mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the filtering will be handled by your Controller, and you will see these values being passed to the controller in the `_search` and `filters`.

The reason the `loadonce: true` is working on the first page is that it is doing the filtering on the client side.

I would suggest checking out Oleg's answer on filtering at the link below, it is what put me on the track to do server side filtering for my application.

[ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Implementation of searching in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid)